# Is there an s3 bucket "flat view", without the folder hierarchy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there an s3 bucket "flat view", without the folder hierarchy, in the AWS Console? Since the structure is flat anyway?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you can use the awscli as follows: aws s3 ls --recursive s3://mybucket.

Comment: Careful with the assumption that S3 is a key/value pair. S3 is an object store with keys, metadata and data. An S3 bucket is actually flat, there is no folder structure. This is emulated by using the seperator '/'.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, that it is flat. Updated.